# OleDb App performing slowly on Windows 7

Tags: c#, performance, windows-7, ado.net, windows-xp

I'm working on refactoring a Windows form application that adjusts time punches in an .mdb file. The program does some rounding up/down on punches based on factors like their proximity to lunch, breaks, end of work day, etc., as well as calculates wages based on overtime requirements. It's also used as a GUI to lookup specific time entries and manually correct bad punches (wrong customer id, task number, etc.). Nothing too complex. The application was originally written in 2004 using ADO.Net. It works fine on the XP computers in the office, but it crashes immediately on anything running Windows 7, which is why I started refactoring it. I decompiled it using .Net Reflector and made a c# project that I've been working on in Visual Studio Express 2012. There were a couple syntax errors that I had to fix before I could recompile, but after I did I had an application that completely works on Windows 7 (I ran a decent number of tests against the original app and I'm confident that the recompiled version is performing the adjustments correctly). I couldn't tell you why exactly it worked with so few changes, but there you have it (I wouldn't mind finding that out either, but it's not my main question). The problem I'm having is that a calculation that takes ~1 minute on a dinosaur running XP takes ~20 minutes on a fresh-out-of-the-box desktop running Windows 7. This particular calculation involves automatically processing unprocessed records (which are marked by a boolean field in the table) when the application starts up. The table the records are coming from has ~235000 records, of which ~250 are marked as unprocessed. Reducing the number of unprocessed records to five takes the time down to ~10 minutes, while reducing the number of total records to a few thousand makes the program run nearly instantaneously; however, that's not really an option at this point. Running the app in debug mode has let me trace the problem to this method:

```
[HelpKeyword("vs.data.TableAdapter"), DebuggerNonUserCode, DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public virtual dsHours.workDataTable GetDataByWeek(string EmployeeID, DateTime? Date_Entered, DateTime? Date_Entered1)
    {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
        if (EmployeeID == null)
        {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = EmployeeID;
        }
        if (Date_Entered.HasValue)
        {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = Date_Entered.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        if (Date_Entered1.HasValue)
        {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[2].Value = Date_Entered1.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[2].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        dsHours.workDataTable dataTable = new dsHours.workDataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

The WorkDataTable class is just a class that extends System.Data.DataTable and implements System.Collections.IEnumerable, and adds specific formatting for the work table in the .mdb back end. If anyone could point me in the right direction in figuring out why this code runs so slowly, I'd really appreciate it. And of course if you need more code/information I'll be willing to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fundamental problem with this method. The problem is probably how many times it is called during processing. Try to re-factor your sql to pull all your data at once, up front - then process while all your data is in memory. With LINQ, it should be simple to make these changes. Changing from MS Access to something like SQL Server Express wouldnt hurt, either.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem like the method is being called too often, so I'm working on changing that. Even so, the program runs well enough on XP, do you have any idea why it's so much slower on 7?

Comment: It could be the version of the Jet OleDb drivers.

Comment: In that vein, I tried installing the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 and using it as my connection provider. Everything runs quickly now, so thanks for the tip!